# Error in npm install command

Tags: node.js, git, angularjs, npm, karma-runner

Got an error at the end of `npm install` command.

```
angular#1.2.1 bower_components\angular
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma-requirejs does not satisfy its siblings'
peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma@0.10.10 wants karma-requirejs@~0.2.0

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd F:\AngularExamples\KarmaTest546\AngularJS-Testing-Article
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9

npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:

npm ERR!     F:\AngularExamples\KarmaTest546\AngularJS-Testing-Article\npm-debug
.log

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

although I have allowed to clone git under `http` instead of `git` using `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

package.json :-

```
{


"name": "yom-angularjs-testing-article",



"version": "0.0.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/matsko/YOM-AngularJS-Testing-Article"
  },



"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/bower install"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/yearofmoo/YOM-AngularJS-Testing-Article",
  "devDependencies": {


 "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-css": "~0.5.4",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.1.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-shell": "~0.2.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "karma-mocha": "latest",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "latest",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-ng-scenario": "latest",
    "chai": "1.4.0",
    "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma": "~0.10.2",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.6.2",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.2",
    "ng-midway-tester": "2.0.5",
    "bower": "~1.2.7"

  }
}
```

can some one suggest a solution for this?

Comment: What does packages.json look like

Comment: kindly find updated post with package.json file content

Comment: Well, karma 0.10 requires karma-requirejs 0.2, you specified 0.1. Perhaps adjust that to meet the requirement, if you can

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Really appreciate your immediate response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `karma 0.10` requires `karma-requirejs 0.2` as you can see:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma-requirejs does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements! 

npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma@0.10.10 wants karma-requirejs@~0.2.0
```

However in your package.json you specified `karma-requirejs` `0.1`.

Adjust that to meet the requirement and it should work

Comment: What is the actual command you type to adjust `npm` to meet this kind of requirement? I am getting a similar error with `EPEERINVALID react-dom@0.14.7 requires a peer of react@^0.14.7 but none was installed.`, but have already done `npm i -g react@^0.14.7`.

Answer (score 2):

upgrade karma version .. that’s it  .. 
`"karma": "~0.12.0"`